# Django sessions not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: django, internet-explorer, session, cookies, session-cookies

Sessions work perfectly in all other browsers that I have tested.

If I try to get the session id with `sessionid = request.COOKIES['sessionid']`, I get this error: `KeyError: 'sessionid'`

This is what I have in my settings.py:

```
CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.vb.is'
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
```

Sites are vb.is, fiskifrettir.vb.is and hestabladid.vb.is

[image]

Server setup is: apache2 (mod_wsgi) and nginx

Comment: Are cookies enabled in that browser?

Comment: Yes, no one can log in with IE.

Comment: Execute this: print request.session.session_key.  And take a look whether the sessionid is defined or not.

Comment: Defined, yes. But I get a new one every time. See for yourself: http://www.vb.is/site-info/

Comment: Also, I tried setting `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'vb.is'` (See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095944/what-is-the-correct-value-for-session-cookie-domain-if-my-django-site-is-set-up-o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting a cookie on XX.XX won't work in general. See Q#6 here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx and see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/19/private-domain-names-and-public-suffixes-in-internet-explorer.aspx.

You can avoid the problem by setting the cookie with domain=WWW.vb.is instead.

Comment: I presume that's to stop sites from setting cookies for ".co.uk" and likes.

Comment: setting the cookie for www.vb.is won't help since I need to access that cookie from secure.vb.is for my current setup to work. So what you're saying is that I just can't have cross-domain persistent sessions...